# Visual Studio - Change colors from blue to purple

Tags: visual-studio

I got this problem where my code editor looks like:

[image]

while I want it to look like:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: [Visual Studio Formatting -- Change Method Color - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806420/visual-studio-formatting-change-method-color)

Comment: [SemanticColorizer - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreasReischuck.SemanticColorizer)

Comment: [Enhanced Syntax Highlighting - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StanislavKuzmichArtStea1th.EnhancedSyntaxHighlighting)

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill. Feel free to add them as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Answer written :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I change the syntax highlighting colours in Visual Studio?

There are a couple of add-ons that will make this easy for you:

[SemanticColorizer - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreasReischuck.SemanticColorizer):

> **Semantic Syntax Colorizer**
>
> A Visual Studio 2015 & 2017 editor extension for semantic syntax
>   highlighting.
>
> It uses the Roslyn APIs to highlight the following syntax types in
>   distinctive colors to make them easily recognizable.
>
> To change the colors use the regular Visual Studio "Font and Colors"
>   Options. Look for Semantic * in the "Display items".
>
> - Class fields
> - Enum fields
> - Static methods
> - Regular methods
> - Constructors
> - Type parameters
> - Parameters
> - Namespaces
> - Class properties
> - Local variables
> - Special types (built in)
> - Normal types
>
> The code is fairly simple, but it is not currently written using the
>   Async APIs in Roslyn.
>
> This extension works for the first final version of Visual Studio 2015
>   and all successors.

[Enhanced Syntax Highlighting - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StanislavKuzmichArtStea1th.EnhancedSyntaxHighlighting):

> **Enhanced Syntax Highlighting**
>
> Visual Studio editor classifier extension based on the async Roslyn
>   APIs to highlighting C# and Visual Basic code.
>
> There are syntax highlighting for "Events", "Fields", "Fieds
>   (Constant)", "Fields (Inside Enums)", "Local Variables", "Methods",
>   "Methods (Extension)", "Methods (Static)", "Namespaces", "Parameters"
>   and "Properties".

See also [Visual Studio Formatting -- Change Method Color - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806420/visual-studio-formatting-change-method-color) for more discussion.